# Differential equation with absolute value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

After some algebraic simplification, I got the ODE:
$$\ddot x(t)+\sqrt {(\dot x(t)+x(t))^2}+k x(t)=0$$
I interpreted this equation as:
$$\ddot x(t)+|{(\dot x(t)+x(t))}|+k x(t)=0$$
I have some problem to solve it. 
Could you give me some hint please?
Thanks.

Comment: Normally when I have absolute values I split the problem into two cases.

Comment: You may use Godisemo's hint and then it becomes a 2nd ordered linear ODE with constant coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is equivalent to

$$\ddot x(t)\pm\dot x(t)\pm x(t)+kx(t)=0$$

so you have to solve the equations

$$\ddot x(t)+\dot x(t)+(1+k)x(t)=0 \qquad \ddot x(t)-\dot x(t)-(1-k)x(t)=0.$$

The solutions of these equations can be obtained by solving the characteristics equations

$$\lambda^2\pm\lambda+(\pm 1+k)=0$$

giving

$$\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{\mp 1\pm\sqrt{1-4(\pm 1+k))}}{2}$$

and depending on the value of $k$ you will get different sets of solutions.