# How to manage the absolute value on a differential equation  $|T(x)'+A(T,x)+B(T,x)| = f(T,x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value

Hi everyone I need to solve an equation of this type:

$|T(x)'+A(T,x)+B(T,x)| = f(T,x)$

with boundaries conditions.

The absolute value is my problem. Of course without it, the solution of these is well treated in the literature.

After search in the questions I found this:
[Differential equation with absolute value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120848/differential-equation-with-absolute-value)

So, can I do the same procedure?
Or there is another way to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Crosspost on Computational Science: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2212/

Comment: Cross posting on different sites simultaneously is discouraged. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu/64073#64073
Wait for a couple of days before deciding to cross-post.

Comment: ok I deleted the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation does not determine $T'$ in terms of $T$ and $x$, so uniqueness of solutions may be a problem.  You can say $T'$ is either $f(T,x) - A(T,x) - B(T,x)$ or $-f(T,x) - A(T,x) - B(T,x)$.  Presumably there will be one region where it's the first and one region where it's the second, and (assuming $f,A,B$ are continuous) if you want $T'$ to exist everywhere it'll be impossible to switch between one and the other except when $T' = 0$.

Comment: Thank you Robert. But can you explain me why you only take two combinations and not more? I mean why not $f(T,x)+A(T,x)−B(T,x)$ for instance ?

Comment: $|t|$ is either $t$ or $-t$ (assuming we're talking about real numbers).

Comment: Does not matter if A(T,x) and B(T,x) are negatives right?. Thank you very much!

Comment: Right.  Why would it matter?